# ヘルプセンターのチャットに関する表現について

Tags: 討議, ヘルプ, チャット

項目を3つ、[別質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2381/)に移動させました。

---

ヘルプで「チャットルームの作成」ページで、ページ右に、

> この権限
>   新しいチャットルームを作成する
>   ✓ あなたはこの権限を獲得しました

とあり、現在のこの表現では、今そのタイミングで獲得したように見えます。
しかしこれは信用度によって獲得したものですよね?
「あなたはこの権限を持っています」
などの表現の方が良いのでは、と思います。

---

同じく「チャットルームの作成」ページにおいて、

> ルームで話すことができるのは、親サイトでチャット権限を保持しているユーザーだけであることに気を付けてください。

とあります。この中で「チャット権限」という言葉が気になりました。
ヘルプセンターの権限のページを見ると、チャットに関する権限は2つあり、

- チャットルームの作成
- チャットで話す

とのことですが、「チャットで話す」の説明が「このサイトのチャットルームに参加する」となっています。
なんだか、

- 作成
- 参加
- 会話

の3つの権限があるようにも見えるし、更に「チャット権限」という言葉がどれを指すのかもしばらくよく解りませんでした。
「このサイトのチャットルームに参加する」→「このサイトのチャットルームに参加して話す」
「チャット権限」→「チャットで話す権限」
と修正すると良いのでは、と思いました。

---

以上です。

Comment: 原文はearnedですので持っているを獲得しているに変えて、"あなたはこの権限を獲得しています"という提案を[しておきました](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40287039?qt=%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E6%A8%A9%E9%99%90%E3%82%92%E7%8D%B2%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F)。(もし提案した文章を変えてほしいとかありましたらコメントでご指摘ください)

Comment: コメントからチャットに案内されることへのご意見と、ヘルプの文言は別の話題ではないでしょうか。どういう表現にするかをこのコメント欄で話すのも場違いのように感じますし、別質問にしていただけませんか？

Comment: @unarist 「チャットへの案内と結果の扱いについて」「チャットに関する表現について」の2つに分離しましょうか? 前者は質問中最初の項目と最後の項目、後者は残り、と考えています。

Comment: @sun-solar-arrow  私は直訳する必要はないと思っていて、原文が "earn" だからといって「獲得」という言葉を使うべき、とは思っていません。日本語には日本語の自然な表現というものがあると思います。でもこの場合は「獲得しています」でも構わないかな、と思います。

Comment: はい、その2つでいいと思います。訳文に関しては私も[チャットの方で少し書いてしまいましたが](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34059977#34059977)、まあ後ほど。

Comment: すみません、見落としていましたが、現在の最初の項目も案内に関する話ですし、もう一つの質問に移した方がいいと思います。要は、単なる不自然な文章だけをこちらで扱いたいと思ったのです。

Comment: @unarist 移動しました。

Comment: @masm 確かに、信用度は増減もしますし持っているに変えときます。(回答も移動します)

Answer (score 2):

> 「あなたはこの権限を持っています」などの表現の方が良いのでは、と思います

Transifexで`この権限を持っています`と訳しました。

> 「チャット権限」→「チャットで話す権限」と修正すると良いのでは、と思いました。

賛成です。用語がたくさんあって、新規ユーザーに理解されない可能性があるからです。