# コメントからチャットへの案内と結果の扱いについて

Tags: 討議, コメント, チャット

[元の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2377/)から分離しました。

---

コメントで質問者とやりとりしていると、

> 長時間におよぶディスカッションをコメントで行うことは避けてください。自動的にこのディスカッションをチャットに移動させますか?

という表示が現れました。
この理由が解りません。私の頭の中では、

- チャット: 両者がその場(PC の前)にいて、やりとりが交される。従ってきっと短時間で解決する。
- コメント: 片側がコメントした時にもう片側がいないことが多い。従って解決まで時間がかかる。

と思っています。なので、「長時間=コメント」と思っており、それを避ける理由が解りません。
避けるべきは短時間で何回にもわたる往復コメント(まさにチャット)ではないでしょうか?

---

また、「自動的にこのディスカッションをチャットに移動させますか?」という表示が出ますが、これををクリックするとどうなりますか?
即座に移動させられるのでしょうか? それともワンクッションあってキャンセルできますか?
相手は移動した人が呼ばないといけないのか、自動的に呼ばれるのか、どちらでしょうか?
この辺が判らないため、あまりクリックしてみる気にならないです。

---

チャットルームでの成果はどうなるのでしょうか? このサイトでは

- コメントでなくできるだけ質問の編集を
- コメントでなくできるだけ回答の編集を
- コメントは後から来た人には読みづらい

と散々言われています。
チャットルームでの成果は、コメント以上に目が向けられないと思いますので、チャットルームの成果が放置されているのはもったいないと思います。
自動的に回答(または「チャットでの成果」など)として投稿されると良いのではないでしょうか?
(既にそういう機能があるならすみません)

---

以上です。

Comment: meta.stackoverflow の[この回答](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95938) にはそのメッセージは「2人のユーザ間で短期間にコメントが往復してる場合にだけ出る」というような旨書かれています．これを信じるなら今回問題になっているコメントも相当チャットっぽかった（実際どうだっかは置いておいて，誤判定としては許容できる程度にそれらしかった）のではないでしょうか． / またここでいう「長時間」はやり取りに時間がかかるという意味ではなくて「ずらずら続く」みたいな意味だと思います．翻訳の問題？

Answer (score 4):

自分の考えを書いておきます。

```
長時間におよぶディスカッションをコメントで行うことは避けてください。自動的にこのディスカッションをチャットに移動させますか?
```

[Why must we "avoid discussions in comments"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95937/332584) が参考になると思います。この[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95938/332584)によると

> たくさんコメントしているとぐちゃぐちゃになり、あとから来た人が状況を把握するのは難しい

とのことです。(雑な翻訳です)

---

> また、「自動的にこのディスカッションをチャットに移動させますか?」をクリックするとどうなりますか?

ワンクッションあるかは分かりかねますが、ユーザーは自動的に呼ばれると思います。

> 自動的に回答(または「チャットでの成果」など)として投稿されると良いのではないでしょうか?

良いと思います。ですが、結果をまとめて自己回答すればいいかなとも思います。

Answer (score 3):

- *コメントは後から来た人には読みづらい*

*チャットルームでの成果は、コメント以上に目が向けられない*

この部分については、大いに賛成です。長大なコメントでのやり取りが非常に読みづらいのは確かですが、それを回避するのにそれ以上に読みづらいチャットの使用を推奨するというのは本末転倒でしょう。私はこの「チャットへの案内」と言うのは現在のStackOverflowのシステムの中で最低最悪のものだと思っています。

運営側は一体この「チャットへの案内」がどれだけ正しい回答の投稿に役立っているのか、ちゃんとした統計をお持ちなのでしょうか。私がこの半年間本家StackOverflowを利用してみた感覚から言うと一旦コメントがチャットに移動してしまうと、そのまま回答も付かない(当然承認された回答にはならない)ままで放置されてしまう率が極めて高いように感じています。(質問者にとってはマンツーマンで解決策を得られれば、わざわざそれが「回答」の形になるのを待って「承認」するなんて必要性はないのですから、当然の帰結だと思います。)

現実問題としてきちんとした回答を得られる率が低い(私の感覚ではなくきちんとした統計データとして)のであれば、「チャットへの案内」自体をやめて別の方法で長々とした議論を行わないよう促す方が、サイト全体の質の向上策としては効果的だろうと思います。

種々雑多なチャットの中身から自動的に回答を投稿するというのは技術的には非常に困難だろうと思いますが、可能なのであれば検討した方が良いですね。それができないのであれば「チャットへの案内」は、すぐにでも廃止すべきです。

Answer (score 3):

今更ながら自分の考えを。。

コメントが長大になることによる弊害は何かというと、今現在の「質問投稿」と「回答投稿」だけを見ても、最新のその質問の解決状況のステータスが、わからなくなることです。スタックオーバーフローが存在する前は、特定の問題が発生してそれをグーグルで検索したときに、さまざまなフォーラムで、それが言及されることはあれど、結局どれも未解決（よくわからない）であることが、それぞれのスレッドを読み込んだ結果わかる、ということがあったらしいです。それを解決するために、「質問」と「回答」で情報を統一化し、それ以外の情報があるならばコメントで、ただし、本来「質問」や「回答」に含めるべき情報をコメントだけに記載しておくことは推奨されない、というのが今のスタックオーバーフローだと認識しています。

この認識に立った時に、一番良いのは、「コメントを通じて情報を整理していく、情報が整理されて不要になったコメントたちはアーカイブしていく」だと個人的には考えます。というのも、古いコメントが乱立している状態で、例えば: 「この回答は昨日リリースされたバージョンだともう古くて使えないよ！」であったり、「新しいバージョンに対応した回答を投稿したよ」を新規にコメントしたとしても、それはその前に投稿された古いコメントたちの中に埋もれてしまいます。

スタックオーバーフローは、この「アーカイブ」のためにチャットを利用できるように、どうやらデザインされている様子です。実際、モデレータであると、「特定の投稿(質問投稿 or 回答投稿)に紐づいたコメントたちを一気にチャットに移動する」であるとか、「コメントの整理」（削除・編集・などなど）が行えるようになっています。

問題は、このコメントの整理権限は、いまのところモデレータにしかない様子です。おそらくこれは、コメントの整理というのを自動的に信用度によって付与するのは、何かしら仕組み的によくないことになるから、こうなっているのかと思っています。ひとまず、コメントに対して、「もう古いからいらないよ」通報がある様子なので、これを回していけば（モデレータがこの通報を受けてコメントを整理していけば）、不要コメントのモデレーションを行うことはできる様子です。

ここからさらに個人的な推測ですが、このような運用を回した場合に、コメントがもりもりと伸びていっている状態さなかにあるメンバーが、後からモデレータに通報して、モデレータがコメントを整理するのをまって、をやらなくてはならなくのを見越しながら、投稿にコメントをひたすら付与していくのは、少し冗長です。であったら、その渦中にいるメンバーが、自分でチャットに移動させられるようにしたらいいんじゃないか、という発想で、この「チャットに移動」が実装されたのではないか、と思っています。

ひとまず、なので、無理にコメントをチャットに移動させる必要はないとは思います。一通りやり取りが終わり、質問・回答投稿が整理された後に、あまりにもコメントが散らかっているようであったら、モデレータにコメント（群）を通報していただければ、それをチャットに移動するなどして、コメントの整理を行っていくことができると思います。